# Programmatic interaction with Excel radio buttons and checkboxes using Apache POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am currently wrapping my head around a reporting sheet provided in Excel (.xlsx) that I have to fill for the reimbursement of travel expenses. This document is a monster and significantly slows down my computer, so I decided to build a little "generator" so I do not have to open the .xlsx file for editing. The idea was to provide all information in a simple .csv file, read this data programmatically, and use Apache POI to fill all the data into the right places.

I managed to get the simple cases to work:

```
Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(new File("in.xlsx"));
Sheet s = wb.getSheet("Sheet X");
s.getRow(16).getCell(12).setCellValue("some value");
...
FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("out.xlsx");
wb.write(fileOut);
fileOut.close();
```

Unfortunately, the reporting sheet also contains checkboxes and radio buttons that automatically set some fields and I don't understand how to access these, let alone "click" them programmatically. I have started to read the XML that is generated by Excel and I found the `<controls>` section inside a sheet XML. I am not allowed to share the file, but it contains checkboxes like:

```
<control shapeId="8193" r:id="rId5" name="Check Box 1">
    <controlPr defaultSize="0" autoFill="0" autoLine="0" autoPict="0">
        <anchor moveWithCells="1">
            <from><xdr:col>5</xdr:col><xdr:colOff>558800</xdr:colOff><xdr:row>16</xdr:row><xdr:rowOff>12700</xdr:rowOff></from>
            <to><xdr:col>5</xdr:col><xdr:colOff>1028700</xdr:colOff><xdr:row>17</xdr:row><xdr:rowOff>0</xdr:rowOff></to>
        </anchor>
    </controlPr>
</control>
```

Or radio buttons like:

```
<control shapeId="5121" r:id="rId6" name="Group Box 1">
    <controlPr defaultSize="0" autoFill="0" autoPict="0">
        <anchor moveWithCells="1">
            <from><xdr:col>3</xdr:col><xdr:colOff>25400</xdr:colOff><xdr:row>16</xdr:row><xdr:rowOff>0</xdr:rowOff></from>
            <to><xdr:col>7</xdr:col><xdr:colOff>12700</xdr:colOff><xdr:row>17</xdr:row><xdr:rowOff>0</xdr:rowOff></to>
        </anchor>
    </controlPr>
</control>
<control shapeId="5122" r:id="rId7" name="Option Button 2">
    <controlPr defaultSize="0" autoFill="0" autoLine="0" autoPict="0">
        <anchor moveWithCells="1">
            <from><xdr:col>3</xdr:col><xdr:colOff>571500</xdr:colOff><xdr:row>16</xdr:row><xdr:rowOff>12700</xdr:rowOff></from>
            <to><xdr:col>3</xdr:col><xdr:colOff>977900</xdr:colOff><xdr:row>17</xdr:row><xdr:rowOff>0</xdr:rowOff></to>
        </anchor>
    </controlPr>
</control>
...
(there are always three radio buttons per group)
```

From reading the XML content of the .xslx file and playing around with the settings that I actually CAN set through POI, I found out the following so far:

- (Un-) Ticking the checkboxes sets a specific target cell to TRUE/FALSE and selecting a radio button sets a specific target cell to some value. The "anchor" in my examples only seems to affect the sheet design and the actual binding and configuration of the values is done in the xl/ctrlProps/*.xml files, which you see when extracting the .xlsx file. To find the right file, you need to find the r:id of the control in the `xl/worksheets/_rels/*.rels` file, which again points to the right file in `ctrlProps`.
- It turns out that these bindings are actually bi-directional, so writing TRUE to the referenced cell also ticks the checkbox when I open Excel again. In the same way, writing the right number to the target cell also selects the right radio button. However, Apache POI only has limited capabilities when it comes to execute embedded code that might be triggered by controls. As a result, my programmatic changes do not seem to propagate to all cells of the sheet, even though the missing cells only contain simple in-line calculations.
- As @racraman points out, it is possible to "recalculate" the results from simple expression.

Right now, I am trying to find an answer to the following two main questions:

1) Where in the .xlsx file structure do I find the VBA macros to see what would be executed on-click in Excel?

2) When it comes to the "recalculation"... why would this even be necessary for dynamically calculated cells? Are the evaluation results stored in the document as well? I always thought that Excel computes everything on the first opening, but I understand that it would make sense to store them for potentially faster load times.

I would highly appreciate any pointers.

Comment: I hate to be the bearer of bad news, but POI is not an Excel engine/simulator, but simply a library for us to read/write it's files.  For example, we can save a checkbox as being in a checked or unchecked state, but that's not a programmatic triggering of it (ie. if Excel triggers some VB code when the user clicks it .... well, POI doesn't do that).  Unfortunately, most businesses mega-spreadsheets are built precisely to use these triggers.  Instead, I would recommend writing the functionality you need in Excel VBA.

Comment: It is worth mentioning that if the spreadsheet consists solely of simple formulae (eg "A1+B1"), if you set A1 and B1 then POI does have some recalculation ability - see http://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/eval.html#recalculation .

Comment: You cannot access any macro in this file, because `xlsx file structure ` is designed for **NOT** hosting macros, (however the `.xlsm` supports macros)